# Determine sample size according to some unknown distribution with given error rate and confidence

Tags: confidence-interval, sample-size

Assume $x\in\mathbb{N}$ obey some unknown distribution, and I can sequentially  and independently acquire infinite samples of $x$.  Now, given an error rate $\epsilon$ and confidence $1-\delta$, can I find a sufficiently large number $m$ that if I draw $m$ samples, the probability of drawing a sample beyond the maximum value $M$ observed is less than $\epsilon$ with confidence $1-\delta$?

(That is, if I already got a sample $S_m = \{x_1, \ldots, x_m\}$, then $Pr[Pr[x_{m+1}>\text{max}\{x_i | x_i\in S_m\}]\geq\epsilon]\leq\delta$)

Comment: I've got a pretty solution, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923474/determine-sample-size-according-to-some-unknown-distribution-with-given-error-ra).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an exact dup of crossposted https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923474/determine-sample-size-according-to-some-unknown-distribution-with-given-error-ra